# Actionmailer URL adds subdir twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, actionmailer

I have a pretty standard rails 5.1 app which is mounted under a subdir under our main domain:

https://www.company.com/subir/

This is done in routes.rb

```
scope :subdir 
  the other routes
end
```

I use NGINX in our DMZ to pass incoming requests to my application server:

```
...
server_name www.company.com;

 location /subdir {
   proxy_pass https://my-app-server;
 }
...
```

on my app-server is the pretty common combo Nginx/Puma installed and almost everything works fine, except the urls which are in the emails I send via actionmailer.

In my view I have a link:

```
link_to 'approve customer', admin_customer_url(@customer)
```

This creates the following:

```
https://www.company.com/**subdir/subdir**/admin/customer/:id
```

On my local machine these links are generated correctly in my emails, but not in staging environment on my app-server.

I dumped the request object in a view to see if my nginx setup is crazy but there is nothing obviously crazy...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have config.action_mailer.default_url_options set in your environment file.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: yes: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'company.com'}

Answer (score 0):

For the records: in deploy/staging.rb I still exported ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']. This added the subdir twice to app.base_path and this was causing my issue.